# Android app not working on some devices that it was working on before

Tags: java, android

I have an app that works on several Android devices. However on some it crashes as soon as you open the app. I don't know what the problem is, but here is the logcat from one of the devices that is not working:

```
02-13 18:38:54.130 17779-17779/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.

02-13 18:38:54.170 17779-17779/? I/SELinux: Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9195_4.4.2_0055


02-13 18:38:54.170 17779-17779/? I/SELinux: selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
02-13 18:38:54.170 17779-17779/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> Normal User
02-13 18:38:54.170 17779-17779/? E/dalvikvm: >>>>> com.reelychat.reelychat [ userId:0 | appId:10269 ]
02-13 18:38:54.170 17779-17779/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-13 18:38:54.260 17779-17785/? E/jdwp: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
02-13 18:38:54.260 17779-17785/? D/dalvikvm: Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
02-13 18:38:54.330 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/reelychat/reelychat/MainActivity$4; (168)
02-13 18:38:54.330 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lcom/reelychat/reelychat/MainActivity$4;' failed
02-13 18:38:54.330 17779-17779/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'com.reelychat.reelychat.MainActivity$4', referenced from method com.reelychat.reelychat.MainActivity.callToStart
02-13 18:38:54.330 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2857 (Lcom/reelychat/reelychat/MainActivity$4;) in Lcom/reelychat/reelychat/MainActivity;
02-13 18:38:54.330 17779-17779/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x000d
02-13 18:38:54.330 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature ([Landroid/util/Size;)
02-13 18:38:54.330 17779-17779/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.util.Size.getHeight, referenced from method com.reelychat.reelychat.MainActivity.choueOSize
02-13 18:38:54.330 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 15719: Landroid/util/Size;.getHeight ()I
02-13 18:38:54.330 17779-17779/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0013
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.util.Size', referenced from method com.reelychat.reelychat.MainActivity.choueOSize
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 1976 (Landroid/util/Size;) in Lcom/reelychat/reelychat/MainActivity;
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0040
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/util/Size;)
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/util/Size;)
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: DexOpt: method is in an interface
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.close, referenced from method com.reelychat.reelychat.MainActivity.closeCam
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 875: Landroid/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice;.close ()V
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejecting opcode 0x6e at 0x0008
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: VFY:  rejected Lcom/reelychat/reelychat/MainActivity;.closeCam ()V
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: Verifier rejected class Lcom/reelychat/reelychat/MainActivity;
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/reelychat/reelychat/MainActivity;)
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418b9da0)
02-13 18:38:54.340 17779-17779/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.reelychat.reelychat, PID: 17779
    java.lang.VerifyError: com/reelychat/reelychat/MainActivity
        at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2296)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2470)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1307)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5593)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Code from main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int user_id;
    CallbackManager callbackManager;

    SharedPreferences preferences;
    int my_user_id;
    int my_age;
    String my_f_id;
    String my_name;
    String my_location;

    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;

    boolean previewStarted = false;

    // camera2 stuff

    private TextureView mTextureView;
    private TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener mTextureViewListner;

    private CameraDevice mCamDevice;
    private CameraDevice.StateCallback mCamDeviceSCallback;

    private String mCamId;
    private static final int requestCamPermisionResult = 0;
    private Size mPreviewSize;

    private CaptureRequest.Builder mCapturRBuilder;

    private HandlerThread bHandlerThread;
    private Handler bHandler;
    RelativeLayout siz;

    private static SparseIntArray orientation = new SparseIntArray();
    static {
        orientation.append(Surface.ROTATION_0, 0);
        orientation.append(Surface.ROTATION_90, 90);
        orientation.append(Surface.ROTATION_180, 180);
        orientation.append(Surface.ROTATION_270, 270);
    }

    private boolean versionCheck(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        preferences = getSharedPreferences("ReelyChat", this.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Intent intent2 = getIntent();
        if(intent2.hasExtra("go")){

        }
        else{
            if (preferences.contains("f_id")) {

                my_f_id = preferences.getString("f_id", null);
                my_user_id = preferences.getInt("user_id", 0);
                my_age = preferences.getInt("age", 0);
                my_name = preferences.getString("name", null);
                my_location = preferences.getString("location", null);

                if (my_f_id == null){
                    facebookInit();
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    siz = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.siz);
                    getCam();


                    facebookCall();
                    // notifyMessage();
                } else {
                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Results.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            } else {
                facebookInit();
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                siz = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.siz);
                getCam();

                facebookCall();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    //        profileTracker.stopTracking();
    }

    private void facebookInit(){
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    }

    private void facebookCall(){
        if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null){
            getFacebookInfo(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken());
        }

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile", "user_location", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                if(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken() != null) {
                    getFacebookInfo(loginResult.getAccessToken());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error) {

            }

        });
    }

    private void getFacebookInfo(final AccessToken accessToken){

        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(accessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                try {
                    Intent intent;
                    intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();

                    System.out.println(accessToken.getUserId());
                    System.out.println(object.getString("first_name"));
                    // System.out.println(object.getString("birthday"));
                    System.out.println(object.getString("gender"));

                    b.putString("user_id", accessToken.getUserId());
                    b.putString("name", object.getString("first_name"));
                    if(object.has("birthday")){
                        b.putString("dob", object.getString("birthday"));
                    }else{
                        b.putString("dob", "");
                    }
                    b.putString("dob", object.getString("birthday"));
                    b.putString("gender", object.getString("gender"));
                    if(object.has("location")){
                        b.putString("location", object.getJSONObject("location").getString("name"));
                    }else{
                        b.putString("location", "");
                    }


                    b.putString("verified", object.getString("verified"));
                    intent.putExtras(b);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id, first_name, birthday, gender, email, location, verified");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }


    /** A basic Camera preview class */
    private void getCam(){
        if(versionCheck()){
            mTextureView = (TextureView)findViewById(R.id.textureView2);
            mTextureView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            callToStart();
        }else{
            mCamera = getCameraInstance();
            // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
            mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
            FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
            preview.addView(mPreview);
        }
    }

    // Camera methods
    public static Camera getCameraInstance(){

        int cameraCount = 0;

        Camera cam = null;
        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
        cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                try {
                    cam = Camera.open(camIdx);
                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return cam;
    }

    public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;

        public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
            super(context);
            mCamera = camera;

            // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
            // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
            mHolder = getHolder();
            mHolder.addCallback(this);
            // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
            mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
            try {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                // Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // empty. Take care of releasing the Camera preview in your activity.
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                mCamera.release();
                mCamera = null;
            }
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
            // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
            // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.

            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
            mCamera.stopPreview();

            if (mHolder.getSurface() == null){
                // preview surface does not exist
                return;
            }

            // Stop preview before making changes
            try {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                // Ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
            }

            // Set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
            // reformatting changes here

            // Start preview with new settings
            try {
                android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = mPreview.getLayoutParams();
                lp.width = siz.getWidth() + 50;
                lp.height = siz.getHeight();
                mPreview.setLayoutParams(lp);
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();

            }
            catch (Exception e){
                // Log.d(TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void printKeyHash() {
        // Add code to print out the key hash
        try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo("YOUR PACKAGE NAME", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
        }
        catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("KeyHash:", e.toString());
        }
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            Log.e("KeyHash:", e.toString());
        }
    }
    //----------------------------------------------------------

    // Camera2 methods
    private void callToStart(){
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mTextureViewListner = new TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
                    setupCam(width, height);
                    conectCam();
                }

                @Override
                public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {

                }

                @Override
                public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surface) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface) {

                }
            };

            mCamDeviceSCallback = new CameraDevice.StateCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onOpened(CameraDevice camera) {
                    mCamDevice = camera;
                    startPreview();
                    previewStarted = true;
                }

                @Override
                public void onDisconnected(CameraDevice camera) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        camera.close();
                    }
                    mCamDevice = null;
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(CameraDevice camera, int error) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                        camera.close();
                    }
                    mCamDevice = null;
                }
            };
        }
    }

    private void setupCam(int width, int heigth){

        CameraManager camManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            try {
                for(String cameraId: camManager.getCameraIdList()){
                    CameraCharacteristics camChhar = camManager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);
                    if(camChhar.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_BACK){
                        continue;
                    }
                    StreamConfigurationMap map = camChhar.get(CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                    int deviseOrientation = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                    int totalRotation = sensorDOrientation(camChhar, deviseOrientation);
                    boolean swapRotation = totalRotation == 90 || totalRotation == 270;
                    int rotatedWidth = width;
                    int rotatedHeigth = heigth;
                    if(swapRotation){
                        rotatedWidth = heigth;
                        rotatedHeigth = width;
                    }
                    mPreviewSize = choueOSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class), rotatedWidth, rotatedHeigth);
                    mCamId = cameraId;
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private void conectCam() {
        CameraManager camManager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    camManager.openCamera(mCamId, mCamDeviceSCallback, bHandler);
                }else{
                    if(shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA)){
                        Toast.makeText(this, "reelyChat requires access to camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    requestPermissions(new String[] {android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, requestCamPermisionResult);
                }
            } else {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    camManager.openCamera(mCamId, mCamDeviceSCallback, bHandler);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void startPreview(){
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
            surfaceTexture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
            Surface preSurface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

            try {
                mCapturRBuilder = mCamDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_PREVIEW);
                mCapturRBuilder.addTarget(preSurface);

                mCamDevice.createCaptureSession(Arrays.asList(preSurface), new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConfigured(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                            try {
                                session.setRepeatingRequest(mCapturRBuilder.build(), null, bHandler);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConfigureFailed(CameraCaptureSession session) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ops looks like there was a problem", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, null);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void closeCam(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mCamDevice.close();
        }
        mCamDevice = null;
    }

    private void startBThread(){
        bHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("reelyChatCam");
        bHandlerThread.start();
        bHandler = new Handler(bHandlerThread.getLooper());
    }

    private void stopBThread(){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            bHandlerThread.quitSafely();
            try {
                bHandlerThread.join();
                bHandlerThread = null;
                bHandler = null;
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    private static int sensorDOrientation(CameraCharacteristics camCharacteristics, int deviceOrientation){
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            int sensorOrientation = camCharacteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
            deviceOrientation = orientation.get(deviceOrientation);
            return (sensorOrientation + deviceOrientation + 360) % 360;
        }
        else
            return 0;
    }

    private static Size choueOSize(Size[] choices, int width, int heigth){
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
            for(Size option : choices){
                if(option.getHeight() == option.getWidth() * heigth / width && option.getWidth() >= width && option.getHeight() >= heigth){
                    bigEnough.add(option);
                }
            }
            if(bigEnough.size() > 0){
                return Collections.min(bigEnough, new compareSizeByArea());
            }
            else{
                return choices[0];
            }
        }
        else
            return null;
    }

    private static class compareSizeByArea implements Comparator<Size> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Size o1, Size o2) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                return Long.signum((long) o1.getWidth() * o1.getHeight() / (long) o2.getWidth() * o2.getHeight());
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if(versionCheck()){
            if(requestCode == requestCamPermisionResult){
                if(grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please grant access to device camera in aplication settings to use this application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onPostResume();
        if(versionCheck()) {
            startBThread();
            if(mTextureView.isAvailable()){
                setupCam(mTextureView.getWidth(), mTextureView.getHeight());
                conectCam();
            }
            else{
                mTextureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(mTextureViewListner);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        if(versionCheck()) {
            if(previewStarted){
                closeCam();
                stopBThread();
            }
        }
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

I know it's a lot of code to look through, but any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean it used to work on some devices and not working now, as in actual same physical device, or you're seeing logs that indicate the same kind of device (but API levels may be diff, etc). But either way it looks related to that Camera line, "Could not find method android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.close, referenced from method com.reelychat.reelychat.MainActivity.closeCam" ... see this possibly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30738502/cameramanager-on-devices-running-lower-than-lollipop

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring Camera2.CameraDevice while it's only available on API 21 and higher, So devices with API20 or lower won't be able to find the class "CAMERA2", so it simply crashes.
You have to split your code and do the declaration inside a separate class (.CS/.Java), Call the one you require after you decide which to use according to what the device API is. something like this (am not sure how) :

```
private void versionCheck() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        this.cameraInterface = Camera2(this);
    }
    else
        this.cameraInterface = Camera1(this);
}
```